# What to call "a liquid that you can use to wash your hand without water and to prevent germs" in general?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Look at this picture

[image]

They are tubes of liquid that you can wash your hands without water.

**How could you wash your hands when you were in a place that has no bathroom or no water?**

People have invented some sort of liquid that you rub on your hands to kill germs, but you don't need any water to wash your hands like you normally do with soap and water.

Do we call it "**dry hand wash**" or something like that in general?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_sanitizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [hand sanitizer](https://www.britannica.com/topic/hand-sanitizer).

Also alternatively: a hand antiseptic, a handrub, a hand rub.

It is a cleansing agent for your hands.

Comment: Hand gel in the UK.